# Access attribute on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Every time I revisit this query it confuses me, and I'm looking for a more thorough understanding.

I have

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :image_categories
end

class PagesController
  def portfolio
    @images = Image.all
  end
end
```

In my view then I want to show all my images and then print out each category name as a class name

```
<%= @images.each do |i| %>
  <div id="item-1" class="isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 ## class names here">
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:image_square_home)) %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add multiple "class names" to your div, since an image has many categories?

Comment: yes that's what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in a helper file (e.g. `PagesHelper` in order to keep your views and models as clean as possible. It could look like this:

```
# app/helpers/pages_helper.rb    
module PagesHelper
  def image_classes(image)
    %w(isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6) + categories_names(image)    
  end

  private

  def categories_names(image)
    image.categories.pluck(:name)
  end
end

# app/views/pages/portfolio.rb
<%- @images.each do |image| %>    
  <%= div_for image, class: image_classes(image) do |img| %>
    <%= image_tag img.photo.url(:image_square_home) %>
  <%= end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it does help clean up the view, is that syntac completely correct though and `class: categories_names` is that correct aswell ? getting wrong number of arguments 0 for 1

Comment: Sorry about this, it had to do with the fact that I didn't pass an argument to the `image_classes ` method at the view. I updated the code, so please give it one more try.

Comment: no problem, next issue however is no implicit conversion of String into Array

Comment: dont worry, got it, use `<<` to add to the array and not `+`

Comment: Try this `image_classes(image).join(' ')` in the view. It seems as if the `div_for` helper, does not accept arrays as options' value.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the following code:

```
<%= i.categories.pluck(:name).join %>
```

This will grab the name of every category associated with the current image into an array, and then join them together into a single string separated by spaces.

In practice, it will look like this:

```
<div id="item-1" class="isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 <%= i.categories.pluck(:name).join %>">
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:image_square_home)) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to add multiple class names to your div, try this:

```
<div id="item-1" class="isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 <%= i.categories.pluck(:name) %>">
```

You may want to use the `try` method if an image could have no categories:

`<%= i.categories.try(:pluck, :name) %>`

Comment: I think that using `try` here is not correct. If an image doesn't have any categories, then an empty `Category::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` will be returned which is never `nil`. If there are no categories, then `pluck(:name)` will return an empty array (`[]`).